# Как переделать ajax запрос с кнопки на сабмит формы?

Tags: php, ajax

Всем привет.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Есть у меня таблица, которая выводит данные из бд в цикле и в этом же цикле записывает.
Посмотрите, как она выглядит:

```
    <?php
     $post = get_cargo();
     foreach ($post as $test): ?>
<form method="post" id="save" class="save">
<tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="del" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$test['id']?>"> </td>                           
        <td><input type="text" name="summa" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="logic" value=""></td>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
</tr></form>
    <? endforeach: ?>
```

Это php-файл, который вносит данные в таблицу:

```
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
$link->set_charset("utf8");
$id = (int)$_POST['id'];
$summa = (int)$_POST['summa'];
$del = (int)$_POST['del'];
$log = strip_tags(trim($_POST['logic']));
$mysql = "UPDATE Users SET logic='$log', sum='$summa', del='$del' WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $mysql);
```

Я сделал по примеру ajax-запрос, который вносит данные в бд без перезагрузки страницы, но он срабатывает только в первой итерации, т.е. в самом верхнем столбце таблицы, в остальных случаях нажатие кнопки не регистрируется.

```
$("#save").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           'dataType': 'json',
           url: "test.php",
            data: {
               id: $('#id').val(),
               summa: $('#summa').val(),
               del: $('#del').val(),
               logic: $('#logic').val(),
               save: true,
           },
           success: function(data) {
               if(data['status'] == 'success'){
                   alert('Данные переданы');
               }
               else{
                   alert('Произошла ошибка!');
               }
           }
       });
    });
Если я правильно понял информацию, то мне нужно сделать форму и принимать данные по сабмиту формы.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, как мне это сделать правильно.
```

Comment: Вам нужен не клик по кнопке, а сабмит формы - https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: @DaemonHK я уже пробовал сменить клик на $(".save").submit(function() 
 и ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Что у вас делает `<tr>` внутри формы?))

Comment: @DaemonHK я уже убрал форму внутрь tr. Только у меня всё равно ничего не хочет работать ¯\(°_o)/¯.
По нажатию кнопки оно срабатывало только для первой строки. 
С сабмитом не срабатывает вообще.

Comment: @DaemonHK ну логично что это часть таблицы, типа список редактируется (это видно по циклу)... У автора куча там дубликатов по `id`. Отсюда и косяки...

Comment: @myudasn с самбитом заработает, просто у вас класс, замените `#save` на `.save`, но положительного результата это не даст...

Comment: @Manitikyl уже заменил и да - не дало

Comment: Если это часть таблицы, тогда форма должны быть в <tr><td>ТУТ ФОРМА</td></tr> Также добавьте какой-нибудь уникальный идентификатор каждой форме, например id (#save-1), а в js используйте вызов по классу (как вариант)

Comment: @DaemonHK так как вы написали - не получится, ибо у него каждая часть редактируемых данных должна быть в отдельном столбце, пусть будет как оно есть.

Comment: @Manitikyl ну, контент в строке, а не в ячейке, вроде не семантично, ну да ладно

Comment: @DaemonHK ¯|_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Ладно, чтобы у вопроса был ответ, и Дух не мучил потом поднятием пустого вопроса. Используйте событие `submit` у формы:

```
$("#save").submit(function(){
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       'dataType': 'json',
       url: "test.php",
        data: {
           id: $('#id').val(),
           summa: $('#summa').val(),
           del: $('#del').val(),
           logic: $('#logic').val(),
           save: true,
       },
       success: function(data) {
           if(data['status'] == 'success'){
               alert('Данные переданы');
           }
           else{
               alert('Произошла ошибка!');
           }
       }
   });
});
```

Чтобы оно сработало вам нужно либо передать id формы в ваш button, либо использовать стандартный `<input type="submit">`

Answer (score 0):

Я не тестил, но **в теории** должно быть как-то так:

```
$(".save").submit(function(){
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       'dataType': 'json',
       url: "test.php",
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function(data) {
           if(data['status'] == 'success') {
               alert('Данные переданы');
           } else {
               alert('Произошла ошибка!');
           }
       }
   });
   return false;
});
```

Ах да, ну и добавьте доп.поле, измените:

```
<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$test['id']?>"> </td>
```

на это:

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$test['id']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="save" value="true">
</td>
```

Хотя по мне, наличие `save` в логике вообще лишнее...

---

`index.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="save" class="save">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="del" value=""></td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="123">
            <input type="hidden" name="save" value="true">
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="summa" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="logic" value=""></td>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </tr>
</form>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".save").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "test.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            if (response['status'] == 'success') {
                alert('Данные переданы');
            } else {
                alert('Произошла ошибка!');
            }
        }
    })
    return false;
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`test.php`:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(['status' => 'success']);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92307/discussion-on-answer-by-manitikyl---ajax-----).